# Managing Debian Services from PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I am making an application for school but i need to be able to manage some Services running on my Debian 7 machine. I'm running `"nginx"` and `"PHP5-FPM"` so `PHP 5.4`. but how can I restart or stop for example `"nginx"` from my PHP file? i tried

```
exec("/etc/init.d/nginx stop");
```

Also I tried

```
shell_exec("/etc/init.d/nginx stop");
```

but no result php returns me:

```
Stopping nginx: nginx
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is for permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be root to restart these services, and unless your web service (like Apache) is running as your site(s) as root, this isn't going to work.  There are a couple of options at your disposal, the best one would likely depend on your situation.

- You can create a two-layered approach where the front-end (run by your web server) issues the commands, and the back-end is a service running as root that executes them.  This could also add a layer of security as the back-end could sanitize the commands before they're executed.  The communication between the front-end and back-end could be any number of things, such as a file that the front-end writes to and the back-end reads from every few seconds, or you could go with WebSockets and make it real-time.
- You could run an additional instance of your web server as root that handles just this task.  You would definitely want to run this over SSL, and it's somewhat risky since if someone could inject code into one of your pages, their code would be running on your server as root.

Comment: i'm gonna go with your second option i think. Cause it will be SSL and all commands are hard coded. but i'll still consider the first one but my linux programming skills are non so that could be a problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd prefer the first, more secure, but in a simpler way, if all you want is stop and start services, you could let php touch some files in a certain directory and have a cronjob that runs in the background check for those files, as a small example touching `nginx_stop` would make the cronjob stop the nginx server and delete the touched file